# Copy files from our local drive to AWS S3 through AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i loged into my `ec2` instance and try to copy files into my `s3`, but it is not recognizing the folder
I want to do in command line not using `winscp`

```
aws s3 cp F:\s3g s3://my-decom-demo/ --recursive --exclude "*.jpg"  --include "*.log"
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Try aws s3 cp \f\s3g s3://my-decom-demo/ --recursive --exclude ".jpg" --include ".log"

Comment: Does your instance have an iam role attached to it? If so does that policy allow the instance to access the s3 bucket?

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognizing the folder"?